# Javascript | Adding value to String Returns an Undefined

Tags: javascript, undefined

I am new to Javascript so please forgive my ignorance.

I got a dynamic table that increases with one row each time the user enters a value.

I'm trying to get all values from the new created column to appear in a TD (id=scm) seperated with a dot.

The following works but returns an "UNDEFINED" at the start.

```
  var serial = document.getElementById("serial");
  var scm = document.getElementById("scm");
  if (scm === ""){
  scm.innerHTML = "start";}
  else {
  scm.innerHTML = scm.value += "." + serial.value }
```

All help is welcome!

Comment: scm === "" dont make sense, is a node not a string, can you create a jsfidle with the html and explain what do you want?

Comment: getElementById returns a DOM object, not a string.

Comment: If you're trying to get values from a newly created row then you cannot be using IDs as per the example above.  IDs must be unique and it looks to me like you're using the same IDs for each new row.  There are also other issues with the code but they're not relevant until that one thing is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I think at the start, the table might not be initialised so you're correct checking for `scm === ""` but you also need to check for undefined (since the table is empty when it loads, right?) so the logic will flow to the else clause and scm will be undefined!

Try adding something like this:

`if (!scm || scm === ""){`

This will check if scm has no value i.e. undefined, OR if it's an empty string. :)

Comment: Actually, (!scm) is true if (scm===""), so it's redundant. Anyway, scm is not a string, it does not make much sense to compare it to "".

Comment: Forget the if statement. It's all about the following line <code>scm.innerHTML = scm.value += "." + serial.value</code> I tried to prepare a JSFiddle, but can't get it to work in there :(

Comment: Exactly Ethannn, when you reach that line in the `else` clause, you've accidentally let it execute whilst `scm` is undefined as anything. Therefore `scm.value` will also by definition be undefined. You need to catch it before it executes or you'll keep getting that `undefined error`, hence the if statement I mentioned.